# Upgrading to 19.04 Hauppauge Quad HDTV Firmware install

Tags: 19.04, firmware, hdtv

The [Github](https://github.com/OpenELEC/dvb-firmware) has an empty README file and I am a little lost as to how to install the Firmware (dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw) to get my Tuners working in Kaffeine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the scriptfile `install` in this very repository should answer your question: https://github.com/OpenELEC/dvb-firmware/blob/master/install

Excerpt:

```
FW_DIR="$DESTDIR/lib/firmware"

mkdir -p $FW_DIR
  cp -a firmware/* $FW_DIR
```

Comment: Thanks Phillip, unfortunately I've now hit another road block. andrew@VERITON:~/Documents/Software/TV/firmware$ sudo cp dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw /lib/firmware
cp: cannot stat 'dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw': No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at what that file is actually called? ;-)